# Pandas dataframe merge by function on column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I say to dataframes.

df_A has columns A__a, B__b, C. (shape 5,3)

df_B has columns A_a, B_b, D. (shape 4,3)

How can I unify them (without having to iterate over all columns) to get one df with columns A,B ? (shape 9,2) - meaning A__a and A_a should be unified to the same column.

I need to use merge with applying the function `lambda x: x.replace("_","")`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 3)), columns=['A__a', 'B__b', 'C'])
```

**df:**

```
   A__a  B__b  C
0     3     0  2
1     0     3  4
2     0     4  4
3     4     2  1
4     3     4  3
```

**df2:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,size=(4, 3)), columns=['A__a', 'B__b', 'D'])

   A__a  B__b  D
0     3     2  0
1     3     1  1
2     0     2  0
3     3     2  0

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], join='inner', ignore_index=True)
df_final = df3.rename(lambda x: str(x).split("__")[0],axis='columns')
df_final
```

**df_final:**

```
    A   B
0   3   0
1   0   3
2   0   4
3   4   2
4   3   4
5   3   2
6   3   1
7   0   2
8   3   2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple concatenation will do

`pd.concat([df_A, df_B], join='outer')[['A', 'B']].copy()`.

or
'`pd.concat([df_A, df_B], join='inner')`

Answer (score 0):

If you cant change the name of the columns in advance and you want to use `lambda x: x.replace("_","")`, this is a way:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.rename_axis(lambda x: str(x).replace("_",""),axis='columns'), df2.rename_axis(lambda x: str(x).replace("_",""),axis='columns')], join='inner', ignore_index=True)
```

Example:

```
d1 = {'A__a' : ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') ,  'B__b' : ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') ,'C': (1,2,3,4,5)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
  A__a B__b  C
0    A    a  1
1    B    b  2
2    C    c  3
3    D    d  4
4    E    e  5

d2 = {'A_a' : ('B', 'C', 'D','G') , 'B_b' : ('l','m','n','o') ,'D': (6,7,8,9)}
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2)
  A_a B_b   D
0   B   l   6
1   C   m   7
2   D   n   8
3   G   o   9
```

Output:

```
   Aa Bb
0  A  a
1  B  b
2  C  c
3  D  d
4  E  e
5  B  l
6  C  m
7  D  n
8  G  o
```

Alternative with:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns={'A__a':'A', 'B__b':'B'}), df2.rename(columns={'A_a':'A', 'B_b':'B'})], join='inner', ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge Dataframe using 'outer'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(5,3)), columns=['A','B','C'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(4,3)), columns=['A','B','D'])

print(df_A.shape,df_B.shape)
#(5, 3) (4, 3)
new_df = df_A.merge(df_B , how= 'outer', on = ['A','B'])[['A','B']]
print(new_df.shape)
#(9,2)
```